# Tennis finals winner with two lose?

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta

Today A. Radwanska reach the semifinals in Singapore in the WTA finals after two losing match during the round robin.

When in the past a tennis player (man or woman) won the finals after losing two matches during the round robin?

Comment: In Wikipedia article about [ATP Wourld Tour finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_World_Tour_Finals) (here is link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ATP_World_Tour_Finals&oldid=630936749)) it is claimed that: *Though it is theoretically possible to advance to the semi-finals of the tournament with two round-robin losses, no player in the history of the singles tournament has won the title after losing more than one round-robin match.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple really - Radwanska reached the semifinals because she, along with 2 other women in her group, all finished with a win-loss record of 1-2 after the round robin part of the tournament. So when players end up tied like that with the same win-loss record they use other stats to determine who advances to the semifinals. First they use sets won and sets lost and create a winning percentage out of that, and then games won versus games lost and the winning percentage for that. If you look [here](http://www.wtatennis.com/SEWTATour-Archive/posting/2014/808/MDS.pdf) you can see that of the 3 players in her group with a 1-2 round robin record, Radwanska had the highest sets winning percentage with 42.86%.

Jelena Jankovic did this same thing just last year in the [2013 WTA Finals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_WTA_Tour_Championships). She ended the round robin stage at 1-2 and made the semifinals because her group also had Sara Errani finish at 1-2 and Victoria Azarenka finish 1-2 so again, Jankovic had the best sets won vs. sets lost winning percentage.